# Using awk to extract two separate strings

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, bioinformatics

MacOS, Unix

So I have a file in the following stockholm format:

```
# STOCKHOLM 1.0

#=GS WP_002855993.1/5-168 DE [subseq from] MULTISPECIES: AAC(3) family N-acetyltransferase [Campylobacter]
#=GS WP_002856586.1/5-166 DE [subseq from] MULTISPECIES: aminoglycoside N(3)-acetyltransferase [Campylobacter]

WP_002855993.1/5-168         ------LEHNGKKYSDKDLIDAFYQLGIKRGDILCVHTELmkfgKALLT.K...NDFLKTLLECFFKVLGKEGTLLMP-TF---TYSF------CKNE------VYDKVHSKG--KVGVLNEFFRTSGgGVRRTSDPIFSFAVKGAKADIFLKEN--SSCFGKDSVYEILTREGGKFMLLGLNYG-HALTHYAEE-----
#=GR WP_002855993.1/5-168 PP ......6788899999***********************9333344455.6...8999********************.33...3544......4555......799999975..68********98626999****************999865..689*********************9875.456799996.....
WP_002856586.1/5-166         ------LEFENKKYSTYDFIETFYKLGLQKGDTLCVHTEL....FNFGFpLlsrNEFLQTILDCFFEVIGKEGTLIMP-TF---TYSF------CKNE------VYDKINSKT--KMGALNEYFRKQT.GVKRTNDPIFSFAIKGAKEELFLKDT--TSCFGENCVYEVLTKENGKYMTFGGQG--HTLTHYAEE-----
#=GR WP_002856586.1/5-166 PP ......5566677788889999******************....**9953422246679*******************.33...3544......4455......799998876..589**********.******************99999886..689******************999765..5666***96.....
#=GC PP_cons                 ......6677788899999999*****************9....77675.5...68889*******************.33...3544......4455......799999976..689*******998.8999**************99999876..689******************9998765.466699996.....
#=GC RF                      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....xxxxx.x...xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

WP_002855993.1/5-168         -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#=GR WP_002855993.1/5-168 PP .....................................................................................................
WP_002856586.1/5-166         -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#=GR WP_002856586.1/5-166 PP .....................................................................................................
#=GC PP_cons                 .....................................................................................................
#=GC RF                      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
//
```

And I've created a script to extract the IDs I want, in this case, WP_002855993.1 and WP_002856586.1, and search through another file to extract DNA sequences with the appropriate IDs. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fileName in *.sto;
do
protID=$(grep -o "WP_.\{0,11\}" $fileName | sort | uniq)
echo $protID
file=$(echo $fileName | cut -d '_' -f 1,2,3)
file=$(echo $file'_protein.faa')
echo $file 
if [ -n "$protID" ]; then
gawk "/^>/{N=0}/^.*$protID/{N=1} {if(N)print}" $file >> 
sequence_protein.file
fi
done
```

And here's an example of the type of file I'm looking through:

```
>WP_002855993.1 MULTISPECIES: AAC(3) family N-acetyltransferase [Campylobacter]
MKYFLEHNGKKYSDKDLIDAFYQLGIKRGDILCVHTELMKFGKALLTKNDFLKTLLECFFKVLGKEGTLLMPTFT
>WP_002856586.1 MULTISPECIES: aminoglycoside N(3)-acetyltransferase [Campylobacter]
MKYLLEFENKKYSTYDFIETFYKLGLQKGDTLCVHTELFNFGFPLLSRNEFLQTILDCFFEVIGKEGTLIMPTFT
YSFCKNEVYDKINSKTKMGALNEYFRKQTGVKRTNDPIFSFAIKGAKEELFLKDTTSCFGENCVYEVLTKENGKY
>WP_002856595.1 MULTISPECIES: acetyl-CoA carboxylase biotin carboxylase subunit [Campylobacter]
MNQIHKILIANRAEIAVRVIRACRDLHIKSVAVFTEPDRECLHVKIADEAYRIGTDAIRGYLDVARIVEIAKACG
```

This script works if I have one ID, but in some cases I get two IDs, and I get an error, because I think it's looking for an ID like "WP_002855993.1 WP_002856586.1". Is there a way to modify this script so it looks for two separate occurrences? I guess it's something with the gawk command, but I'm not sure what exactly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**an update to the original script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file_sto in *.sto; do
   file_faa=$(echo $file_sto | cut -d '_' -f 1,2,3)
   file_faa=${file_faa}"_protein.faa"

   awk '(NR==FNR) { match($0,/WP_.\{0,11\}/);
                    if (RSTART > 0)  a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++ 
                    next; }
        ($1 in a){ print RS $0 }' $file_sto RS=">" $file_faa >> sequence_protein.file
done
```

The `awk` part can probably even be reduced to :

```
awk '(NR==FNR) { if ($0 ~ /^WP_/) a[$1]++; next }
     ($1 in a) { print RS $0 }' FS='/' $file_sto FS=" " RS=">" $file_faa
```

This `awk` script does the following:

1. Set the field separator `FS` to `/` and read file `$file_sto`.
2. When reading `$file_sto` the record number `NR` is the same as the file record number `FNR`.
3. `(NR==FNR) { if ($0 ~ /^WP_/) a[$1]++; next }`: this line works only one `$file_sto` due to the condition in the front. It checks if the line starts with `WP_`. If it does, it stores the first field `$1` (separated by `FS` which is a `/`) in an array `a`; it then skips to the next record in the file (`next`).
4. If we finished reading file `$file_sto`, we set the field separator back to a single space `FS=" "` (see [section *Regular expression*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)) and the record separator `RS` to `>` and start reading file `$file_faa` The latter implies that `$0` will contain all lines between `>` and the first field `$1` is the `protID`.
5. Reading `$file_faa`, the file record number `FNR` is restarted from 1 while `NR` is not reset. Hence the first `awk` line is skipped.
6. `($1 in a){ print RS $0 }` if the first field is in the array `a`, print the record with the record separator in front of it.

**fixing the original script:**

If you want to keep your original script, you could store the `protID` in a list and then loop the list :

```
#!/bin/bash

for fileName in *.sto; do
    protID_list=( $(grep -o "WP_.\{0,11\}" $fileName | sort | uniq) )
    echo ${protID_list[@]}
    file=$(echo $fileName | cut -d '_' -f 1,2,3)
    file=$(echo $file'_protein.faa')
    echo $file 
    for protID in ${protID_list[@]}; do
       if [ -n "$protID" ]; then
          gawk "/^>/{N=0}/^.*$protID/{N=1} {if(N)print}" $file >> 
          sequence_protein.file
       fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you, the modified version of the original script works! I knew my usage of awk wasn't very elegant, so thanks for the alternative as well! I'm a bit new, so I don't completely understand the code yet, but in the output file, if I use the reduced awk command, it gives me both the sequence from the .sto file and the .faa file. Is there an easy fix for this, so I just get the sequence from the .faa file?

Comment: @D.Parker I had a small mistake. I have updated the code. and I will also add some explanation to it.

Comment: @D.Parker I have added some comments. Also, don't forget [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your output file is test.

Using following command gives you only file names:

```
>>cat text | awk '{print $1}' | grep -R 'WP*' | cut -d":" -f2
```

gives me output:

```
WP_002855993.1/5-168
WP_002856586.1/5-166
WP_002855993.1/5-168
WP_002856586.1/5-166
```

Do you want output like that?